# Does the PoE hat fit in the Raspberry Pi case?

Tags: case, poe

Does the [Raspberry PoE](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/poe-hat/) hat fit inside the [Raspberry Pi 3 Case](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-case/)?

And it might be too soon. But would the same PoE hat, on top of a [Raspberry Pi 4](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/), inside a [Raspberry Pi 4 Case](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-case/) also fit?

And by "fit" I mean will the cover go on top of it as it naturally would.

Comment: Where do you think the fan would get air from in the closed case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use it with standard RPi cases above on the 3+, the lid will fit but it gets hot in the office so the fan runs all the time, so I run it with the lid off as it is our main DNS box and I want it close to the centre of the network. The machines in the basement have the lid on them and run ok.

Whilst the board has an extra layer on it, that layer doesn't extend past the USB sockets etc so the overall height is not larger.

I have a 4 running sans case but new case should arrive tomorrow but I don't expect it to be different as the changes in the case are for the new side connectors.

Comment: Can you provide any pictures?

Comment: Only for the 3+ in a few days, the new cases for the 4 are lost in transit so waiting for a new order next week sometime.

Comment: have you gotten your new cases yet @fearghas ?

Comment: Yes - but not had a RPi4 and POEhat to test it with in the same place :(

The old case could be run with the lid off, the new on is a complete lid that doesn't have an open top that you can drop a cover on or have it open. So aside from whether or not it will fit I think it will get too hot if you used in a domestic setting, it is probably ok in a DC but then you will probably use a different case. Likewise there are no side panels that you could leave open. 

The case is simpler and has less bits to get lost but I think the POEhat will be a challenge to keep cool.